# R S4 .Data inheritance error

Tags: r, r-s4

I have three packages, pkgA (defines class 'A'), pkgB (defines class 'B') & pkgC (defines class 'C' and class 'Broken').  The inheritance diagram looks like this:

```
pkgA        Class A
               |
            ---------
            |       |
pkgB    Class B     |
            |       |
pkgC    Class C   Class Broken
```

The definition of 'Broken' is:

```
setClass('Broken', representation('A', content = 'list'))
```

When I try to create a new one, I get this error:

```
> library(pkgC)
> new('Broken', content = list())

Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “Broken” object: Error in getDataPart(<S4 object of class structure("Broken", package = "pkgC")>) : 
  Data part is undefined for general S4 object
```

Does anyone know what is going on?  Is someone else able to reproduce the problem?

I noticed that:

```
> getClass('Broken')
Class "Broken" [package "pkgC"]

Slots:

Name:    .Data content
Class:       A    list

Extends: 
Class "A", from data part
```

contains a .Data part, which I think is wrong.  Where has it come from? Why is it there?  Is this a bug in setClass?

To produce the problem, I required the following files (which are available in a small github repository here: http://github.com/bluewomble/inheritance_problem)

### pkgA

#### pkgA/R/classes.R

```
setClass('A', representation('VIRTUAL'))
```

#### pkgA/NAMESPACE

```
exportClass(A)
```

#### pkgA/DESCRIPTION

```
Package: pkgA
Type: Package
Title: Test package A
Version: 1.0
Date: 2014-03-20
Author: A N Other
Maintainer: A N Other <another@dev.null>
Description: Test
License: GPL
Depends:
    methods
Collate:
    classes.R
```

### pkgB

#### pkgB/R/classes.R

```
setClass('B', representation('A'))
```

#### pkgB/NAMESPACE

```
exportClass(B)
importClassesFrom(pkgA,A)
```

#### pkgB/DESCRIPTION

```
Package: pkgB
Type: Package
Title: Test package B
Version: 1.0
Date: 2014-03-20
Author: A N Other
Maintainer: A N Other <another@dev.null>
Description: Test
License: GPL
Depends:
    methods,
    pkgA
Collate:
   classes.R
```

### pkgC

#### pkgC/R/classes.R

```
setClass('C', representation('B'))

setClass('Broken', representation('A', content = 'list'))
```

#### pkgC/NAMESPACE

```
exportClass(C)
exportClass(Broken)
importClassesFrom(pkgA,A)
importClassesFrom(pkgB,B)
```

#### pkgC/DESCRIPTION

```
Package: pkgC
Type: Package
Title: Test package C
Version: 1.0
Date: 2014-03-20
Author: A N Other
Maintainer: A N Other <another@dev.null>
Description: Test
License: GPL
Depends:
    methods,
    pkgA,
    pkgB
Collate:
    classes.R
```

I'm using R 3.0.2 on Ubuntu.

Comment: why talk about B and C ?!

Comment: Sorry - I should have been clearer in the original post: without classes B and C (and the three packages), I've been unable to replicate the problem - it's only with this exact setup that I experience this problem.

Comment: still one piece missing though: where do you create the Broken class ? I guess this is in a script that loads the other packages via library() right ?

Comment: Yes, the code that fails is: library(pkgC); new('Broken', content = 'list())).  I'll add that into original post.

Comment: could you setup a github repository with your sources, so that it is easy to test it ?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in getting back to you - I've been away. I've added all the required files into a github repository here: http://github.com/bluewomble/inheritance_problem.